# lithium ion battery queries

Tags: voltage, dc, lithium-ion, robotics, charge

I am currently looking at this battery: http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-12V-1800mAh-Super-Rechargeable-Pack-Protable-Li-ion-Battery-EU-Plug-For-CCTV-/400940782911?hash=item5d59eed53f:g:mxwAAOSw5dNWj4Bn

I am going to use it for a slightly large robotics project where 12v is required for several sensors, 4 motors (2 in each output of an l298) and an arduino mega. Since the battery only has a male and femal dc jack (no  regular wires) am I able to use [**this**](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-POWER-SOCKET-FEMALE-12V-12-VOLT-CCTV-CAMERA-CONNECTOR-CABLE-LEAD/322186816780?_trksid=p2141725.c100338.m3726&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150313114020%26meid%3Da878c5973ef54372acb47c87c3471e55%26pid%3D100338%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D29%26sd%3D172096944994) for the male jack to go into so I can plug into a breadboard?

I have used nimh batteries for my last project and the charge of them vary over time and from looking at many different lithium battery packs ive seen that some of them drop charge quite a lot, Is this true for all of them? The reason i am looking at li-ion is because from googling it seems the best choice out of nimh and li-po (cheaper and safer). Would you suggest this a good choice of power supply? (im on a tight budget too)

Comment: At least it's protable...

Comment: Ill assume you meant "portable". I still dont know how reliable it is though and if lithium ion is the best choice

Comment: That appears to be a 3s lithium polymer battery pack. It is impossible to assess the quality of the pack from an E-bay listing. The pack does say 12.6-10.8 V on it, but that is suspicious. 10.8V is 3.6V per cell (if it is 3s). I definitely recommend you purchase from a source which has full specifications available.

Comment: @Physix: no, the link clearly states protable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this connector should fit the one of the battery.

Also, all Lithium rechargeable batteries suffer quite a lot from voltage drop. This should not be an issue, since for the motors the voltage is not critical, and the logic stuff uses regulated 5V anyway. Li-Ion and Lipo are the same thing. The only difference is that the term Lipo is usually applied to batteries in a plastic pouch, whereas cylindrical  cells are branded Li-Ion.

Comment: ok and this particular battery i have chosen, is it alright to use as it smaller than than other regular lithium battery 12v packs?

Comment: No idea what current your motors require, but these batteries can easily supply 1A for 1-2 hours. I guess the current carrying capability of the pack is limited not by the cells but rather by the cable and the connector.